# I get error when I go to previous activity the third time

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-activity

I'm trying to do a button than it function is go to previous activity in a TabWidget

```
        btnVolver.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                String className = getIntent().getStringExtra("webpush");
                Class<?> webpushClass = null;
                try {
                    webpushClass = Class.forName(className);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), webpushClass); 
                 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
//               intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//               intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
//               webPushActivity.this.finishActivity(RESULT_OK);
                 View vista = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("prueba",
                         intent)
                            .getDecorView();
                       setContentView(vista);
```

A--> Actual activty.         B--> Previous Activity

but when I go from A to B, from B to A, from A to B (third click) I get the next error:

```
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.text.Styled.measureText(Styled.java:430)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.text.Layout.measureText(Layout.java:1655)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.text.Layout.getLineMax(Layout.java:689)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:340)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:365)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4050)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)

 06-20 09:23:20.256: E/AndroidRuntime(554):     at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMess
```

Thank's

Comment: looks memory leak issue .....try Intent intent = new Intent(<your activity name>.this, webpushClass);

Comment: I don't need negatives points, I need a good answers! ;) Thank's again.

Comment: is arrogance growing here or shall we focus on the problem

Comment: I`m not sure, but are you trying to start another activity and set a view to the current one?

Comment: just to clear..i am not the down voter :) . btw it will help if you can post your second activity/view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `StackOverflowError` is probably caused by too many nested views(as also hinted by your logcat content).

Look at the following links for further reference:

[Android StackOverflow Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724758/android-stackoverflow-error)

[java.lang.StackOverFlow error. Suspected too many views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762924/java-lang-stackoverflow-error-suspected-too-many-views)

[Stackoverflow: Caused by nested views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946368/stackoverflow-caused-by-nested-views)

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure, but are you trying to start another activity and set a view to the current one?

Comment: I have a three tabs, in a tab I have an activity (A) and I open other(B) activity in the same Tab. In the last activity(B) I have a button for go back to (A). When I click in this button I go to A correctly. Then I go again from A to B again, and from B to A. I get error when I try to go again to B. I hope You undestand me. Thank for your help! ;)