# How do I place an object on the other side of the screen

Tags: android, mobile, lua, coronasdk

I'm writing a program for a mobile app development class that I am taking. The app involves me placing 2 buttons on the screen. I know that when I put /2 it places it in the middle, and when I put /3 it places the button a third of the way from the left of the screen. Since I need two buttons I would like to put one a third of the the way from the left(which I know how to do), and a third from the right(which I don't know how to do). What should I put to accomplish that?

**My code snippet:**

```
myRedButton.x = display.contentWidth /3 
myRedButton.y = display.contentHeight -50 
myGreenButton.x = display.contentWidth /2 
myGreenButton.y = display.contentHeight -100
```

I'm new to the mobile app programming scene, so keep it simple. Thanks!

Comment: Choose your layout with care and tweaking the gravity should help.

Comment: Idek what "gravity" refers to. I have much to learn

Comment: Make sure you are using a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout in your XML file.

Comment: `Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most`

Comment: Are you using corona for coding? Then you can do like: `object.x = display.contentWidth-(display.contentWidth/3)`. This will place the object to an x position of gap `width/3` from the right side of the screen.

Comment: @krs I am using corona for coding, and already have that coded for my first object, however I don't know how to get the other object 1/3 from the right.

Comment: @user1641187: Ok, pls post your code snippet in the question. We will help you...

Comment: @krs myRedButton.x = display.contentWidth /3
myRedButton.y = display.contentHeight -50
myGreenButton.x = display.contentWidth /2
myGreenButton.y = display.contentHeight -100

Comment: @user1641187: I've posted an answer. Check that and see whether you can solve the issue/not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
local myGreenButton = display.newRect(0,0,50,50)
myGreenButton.x = display.contentWidth- (display.contentWidth/3)
myGreenButton.y = 100
```

**OR simply,**

```
local myGreenButton = display.newRect(0,0,50,50)
myGreenButton.x = (2/3)*display.contentWidth
myGreenButton.y = 200
```

Keep Coding.............. :)

Comment: @user1641187: If you find this answer as an useful one, then please mark the answer as accepted, otherwise the question will remain as an unanswered one. Please do remember this in future also. Thanks. Keep Coding..... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used weight for dividing screen into 3 parts and than placed button in it, check if it works.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrLeftContent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrCenterContent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrRightContent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Don't use three `LinearLayout` for accomplish this. It can be done by one `LinearLayout`. This will make view more recursive and you should avoid it.

Comment: That was an suggestion, its upto you what the requirement is.

Comment: i was just suggested you not to make your `Layout` nested please have a look on this thread. [Stackoverflow: Caused by nested views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946368/stackoverflow-caused-by-nested-views/9950339#comment22630565_9950339)

Comment: Ya sure, I understand that, android says it. I used it because I require my layout to be like that, But Did the answer help ?

Comment: i didn't ask the question ;-) so don't know what op is tried i have just answered this question and seen your answer so i have just drop a comment by seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

here i have put three `TextView` you can change it to button as you like . This will put three views in a row which takes same space on screen.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/total_row_holder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/total_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="some other"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#e8f4f9"
         />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/total_value_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:text="you know"
        android:padding="2dp"

        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/net_value_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="some value"
        android:padding="2dp"

        android:background="@android:color/white" />


</LinearLayout>
```