# java.lang.StackOverflowError on Android 2.2+ API 8 & API 10

Tags: android, android-layout, stack-overflow

I've read many articles about this error and i know its about nested views but still couldn't find a solution yet.

I get this error on API 8 (2.2) or API 10 (2.3+) devices. 4.x.+ are working like a charm.

the log is;

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.text.Styled.measureText(Styled.java:430)
at android.text.Layout.measureText(Layout.java:1655)
at android.text.Layout.getLineMax(Layout.java:689)
at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:340)
at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:365)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4150)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1480)
at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3138)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2584)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2176)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2176)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:928)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
a
```

I've just a listview in linearlayout and here is list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/selectable_background_card" >

<!-- android:stretchColumns="*" -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSinif"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtSinif"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <others.TypefaceTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:customTypeface="fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf" />

    <others.TypefaceTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtKapi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:customTypeface="fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf" />

    <others.TypefaceTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPilotad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Y.AVCI"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:customTypeface="fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf" />
</LinearLayout>

<others.TypefaceTextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSinif"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/layoutTime"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layoutTime"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="S2"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:customTypeface="fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutTime"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <others.TypefaceTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtZaman"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+1:33:02.20"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:customTypeface="fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf" />

    <others.TypefaceTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLiderFark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+20.00.5"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:customTypeface="fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is how it looks on 4.x.+ devices.
[image]

Where is the exact problem? Which line should i remove?

Thank you for advices.

Comment: What your TypefaceTextView class looks like?

Comment: here it is; http://pastebin.com/BkByQ92q

Comment: isn't there anybody who can help?

Comment: Succeeded in solving? I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider this comments for your problem

"You have (way) too many nested layouts. You can check out the official Android blog at d.android.com to get tips and tricks on how to optimize layouts."

and

"In my case it was caused by nested layouts (complex list itens) in a list inside a fragment view pager inside another fragment, using v4 support and HoloEverywhere v1.4 libraries.

I had to remove nested fragments and build it in a different way."

Discursion here:  [java.lang.StackOverFlow error. Suspected too many views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762924/java-lang-stackoverflow-error-suspected-too-many-views)